# How do I create API level specific UI (a different UI for tablet and older versions of Android for the same app)?

Tags: java, android, api, user-interface

I want my app display to be consistent across all android devices.

What code do I need to determine API level of user's device, and display appropriate UI Layout?

Example (pseudocode):

```
if Android 6 (API level 23) {
  Display UI-A
} 

if Android 10 (API level 29) {
  Display UI-B
}
```

I have perused documentation and other SO answers and there is no clear way to do this. I want my simple app to have a clean UI accross multiple API levels. This probably involves changing
res->layout files and AndroidManifest.xml, but I am unclear on how to do this properly. I want the UI to change based on device API level, with target level set as default.

Comment: "What code do I need to determine API level of user's device" -- `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` in Java/Kotlin, or add appropriate suffixes to resource directories (e.g., `res/layout-v29/` for layouts to be used on Android 10 and higher, with `res/layout/` for older devices). "and display appropriate UI Layout" -- I would expect the layouts for an Android 6.0 and an Android 10 device to be the same. What would you expect to change? "This probably involves changing
res->layout files and AndroidManifest.xml" -- not usually.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. When I test on Android 6 device, UI looks different from Android 10. Perhaps I must change UI layout files according to device screen density instead of API level?

Comment: "UI looks different from Android 10" -- that does not give us much to go on. "Perhaps I must change UI layout files according to device screen density instead of API level?" -- that too is very unlikely. You might consider asking a separate question, where you provide a [mcve] of a layout that is giving you different results. Upload screenshots of what you are seeing and link to them from your question. Perhaps we can give you some suggestions of layout adjustments or other things to look at. IOW, focus first on finding the source of the problem.

Comment: Okay. I will do some more research and post another question regarding screen density UI differences if necessary :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create different resources directories. So let us say that you need a layout for API 23 and a layout for API 28, you need to create two directories inside your resources folder, one with the name layout-v23 and the other with the name layout-v28 and you need to place your layouts in the respecting directories.
You can read more about this here 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I did not think to look in android resources overview in the documentation :)